# Why is the default colorspace of opencv different in android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I thought that the default colorspace of opencv is BGR?
i've developed a c++ code using opencv for desktop and is now successfully integrated in android using the JNI and NDK, however, i noticed that images are loaded initially RGB colorspace in android and not BGR.

I transformed first the bitmap to Mat in android and passed it to my JNI function.

this turned my world upside down in image processing as it affected my binarization algorithm particularly the cvtColor function(which i do in native c++). Binarized images are not as clean as before and i had to find a way to fix it(before i do 2 times dilation then 1 erosion, but now, its 1 erosion and 2 times dilation), which gives a binary image not as good when i run the code using openCV desktop.

even if a draw a circle with the Mat image using a Scalar(0,0,255) (which is supposed to be red), i noticed its BLUE.

can i load an image in android it its BGR colorspace?

EDIT:

cvtColor(RGB2BGR) shows this in android:
!(https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/q71/s720x720/1979665_10202132337484510_1325794214_n.jpg)

since in opencv for desktop, its the BGR colorspace that is loaded for images, it loads the original image in BGR colorspace:
!(https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/10013535_10202132340924596_1741770081_n.jpg)

when i do cvtColor(BGR2HLS) in opencv for desktop, the result is this:
!(https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1/1920558_10202132339444559_2012886085_n.jpg)

but in android when i do cvtColor(RGB2HLS) the result is:
!(https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/q71/s720x720/1505483_10202132336164477_595021411_n.jpg)

notice that if i do cvtColor(RGB2BGR) then cvtColor(BGR2HLS), it is not the original image that is converted to HLS.

PS: what i mean by android is using the c++ code i imported using the JNI.
its the same c++ code when im using opencv for desktop in visual studio. OPENCV libraries version is the same.

Comment: Pretty sure this depends on the internal storage preferred by the hardware (which in turn depends on for example what graphics processor it uses).

Comment: i've read its about the openGL thingy? how do i know my version of openGL?

Comment: Perhaps use `glGetString​(GL_VERSION​);`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure however that which version of OpenGL it is is less important than for example whose GPU the product uses.

Comment: Android on ARM is Big Endian while on typical x86 desktops is Little Endian, hence the different apparent byte order.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they changed that, in the past for Android it was also loaded as BGR but now it seems RGB.

You can always convert it:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
```

or

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
```

Comment: however, the original image is not what i see. RGB2BGR shows the image with blue shades on some part..

Comment: I do not know what you are doing without seeing the image or the code. Maybe your original image is RGBA and you should do RGBA2BGR instead.

Comment: ill upload it in a few. wait hehe